# Как в discrod.py проверить, является ли текст приглашением на сервер?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу написать бота, который по команде будет скидывать рандомно сгенерированное приглашение на рандомный сервер, но не могу проверить, является ли строка приглашением, помогите реализовать это если возможно

```
@bot.command()
async def randominvite(ctx):
    inv=""
    while not IsInvite(inv): #несуществующая функция, проверяющая является ли строка действующим приглашением на сервер
        inv = "https://discord.gg/"
        for i in range(8):
            inv += random.choice(chars) #chars - массив со всеми строчными и заглавными латинскими буквами, а также цифрами
    ctx.send(inv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def randominvite(ctx):
    guild = random.choice(bot.guilds)
    channel = random.choice(guild.text_channels)
    invite = await channel.create_invite(max_age=3600, max_uses=5, temporary=False, reason= 'test')
    await channel.send(f"discord.gg/{invite.code}")
```